# Which numbers of [0,1) have a unique base g expansion?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Good evening,

i know that is question is rather standard, but unfornunately I have not much knowledge of number theory.

Take $2 \leq g\in \mathbb{N}$. I know that every $x \in [0,1)$ can be represented as $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x_k}{g^k}$ with $x_k \in \{0, .. , g-1\}$.

I know that this repesentation is not unique (for example if $x_k= g-1 ~~ \forall k > N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$). I know that there are  $x \in [0,1)$ with a unique representation (for example if $x_k= 0 ~~ \forall k > N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$).

**Here is my question:** Is there any characterisation of the $x \in [0,1)$ which have a unique base g expansion?

I am very thankful for any reference! With best regards.

Comment: A number has a unique binary expansion iff it is not a dyadic rational. Generalizing, a number $x\in(0,1)$ has a unique $g$-ary expansion iff it is not of the form $x=\frac{n}{g^k}$ for $n,k\in\Bbb{Z}$. Note that these are exactly the numbers that end in all $0$'s in base $g$.

Comment: I would call this *base $g$ expansion*. The word *$g$-adic* means something else (at least, when $g$ happens to be a prime).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I said $g$-ary, not $g$-adic. I'm quite certain I did not just invent that term as a generalization of "binary", "ternary", and "decimal" ("decimary?").

Comment: $g$-ary is fine, me thinks :-) And, @Mario, I did notice!

Comment: The wikipedia page for [0.999...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...) has some discussion of the result.

Comment: I just noted: $\frac{1}{6}$ can not be written as $\frac{n}{3^k}$ with $n,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, right? Thus it's base three expansion should be unique. But: $\frac{1}{6} = 0.01111111111111..._3$, right? Doesn't the contradict the last statement of @MarioCarneiro ("Note that these are exactly the numbers that end in all $0$'s in base g")?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Sorry to bother you again ;) ... But somehow i can't find the mistake in my "counter example" which contradicts your first post. What am I missing ??? With best regards

Comment: @Mat The problem with your counterexample is that it's not a counterexample. ;) The expansion of $1/6$ in base 3 is unique. My apologies for some ambiguity in my earlier statement; I meant to say that the numbers that end in all $0$'s (or all $g-1$'s) are the numbers that *don't* have unique expansions. In other words, a number does not have a unique expansion iff it has a terminating one (since in this case, you can either end with $0$ or $g-1$).

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you! I got "the thing with the zeros" wrong ;) by any chance, do you know any reference? I checked wikipedia and I could not find any statement of that kind.

Comment: @Mat The WP article in fact only discusses the nonuniqeue expansions for $1$, but mentions also base 2 and 3 in "Generalizations". Other than that, think Mario's first comment could be taken as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a proof that supports the characterization stated in the comments:
The $g$-ary representations for numbers $x\in[0,1)$ are of the form 
$$\tag1 x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_kg^{-k}$$
with $x_k\in\{0,\ldots,g-1\}$. Let $(x_k)$ and $(y_k)$ be two distinct digit sequences in $\{0,\ldots,g-1\}$ representing the same number and wlog. $(x_k)$ lexically precedes $(y_k)$, say $x_n<y_n$ whereas $x_k=y_k$ for $k<n$.
Then
$$\begin{align}0&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty y_kg^{-k}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_kg^{-k}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (y_k-x_k)g^{-k}\\&=g^{-n}(y_n-x_n)+g^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (y_{n+k}-x_{n+k})g^{-k}\\&\stackrel{(1)}\ge g^{-n}+g^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (y_{n+k}-x_{n+k})g^{-k}\\&\stackrel{(2)}\ge g^{-n}+g^{-n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(0-(g-1))g^{-k}\\
&=g^{-n}-g^{-n}(g-1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty g^{-k}
\\&=g^{-n}-g^{-n}(g-1)\frac1{g-1}=0.\end{align}$$
Since we end up with equality, we must have equality at $(1)$ and $(2)$.
But equality at $(1)$ holds if and only if $y_n=x_n+1$ and at $(2)$ if and only if for all $k\ge1$ we have $y_{n+k}=0$, $x_{n+k}=g-1$.
Note that in this case we additionally obtain
$$\tag2x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty y_kg^{-k} =\sum_{k=1}^n y_kg^{-k}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^ny_kg^{n-k}}{g^n}.$$
Likewise, if $x=\frac m{g^n}$ in shortest trerms (i.e. with $m$ not divisible by $g$), the $g$-ary *integer* representation of $m$ ands in a nonzero digit, gives us a terminating representation with $y_n>0$ of $x$ via $(2)$, from which we obtain two $g$-ary representations as above.

This shows that a number $x\in[0,1)$ has two different $g$-ary representations if and only if $x=\frac m{g^n}$ with $0<m<g^n$.